# Redirect to some specific page after ending countdown timer

Tags: php, javascript

Is it possible in this code that on finishing the timer it redirects to some specific page automatically.

```
<blink>
    var timestatus = 1;

    function time_dec() {
        time_left--;
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = time_left;
        if (time_left == 0) {
            clearInterval(cinterval);
        }
    }

    function resumetime() {
        //time_left = 50;
        clearInterval(cinterval);
        cinterval = setInterval('time_dec()', 1000);
    }

    function defaultstart() {
        time_left = 50;
        clearInterval(cinterval);
        cinterval = setInterval('time_dec()', 1000);
    }
    defaultstart(); 
</script>
</head> 
    <body> 
        <span id="countdown">50</span>.
        <input type="button" value="stop" id="stopbutton" onclick="stopstarttime()">
    </body> 
</html>
</blink>
```

Comment: Your markup is terrible wrong. And please don't use the `blink` element!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect in javascript, use:

```
window.location = "http://foo.com/foo";
```

This will redirect the user to foo.com/foo

Comment: Thanks dear your code is working, Please tell me one thing more, how can I convert it into minutes and hours. It should show as HH:MM:SS or DD:HH:MM:SS

Comment: how can I convert it into minutes and hours. It should show as HH:MM:SS or DD:HH:MM:SS

Comment: how can I convert it into minutes and hours. It should show as HH:MM:SS or DD:HH:MM:SS